# Move a directory across a network using c#

Tags: c#, networking, directory

I have a folder A, I want to move it from my computer to a server on the network.

I've tried `Directory.Move(A,Server)` but because they don't have the same root it does not work.

`File.Copy(A,Server)` won't work as the folder is read only and can't change permissions.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** *inculding code*

```
string copyFrom = @"folder";
string copyTo = @"\\server\Libraries\Documents";
string destinationPath = Path.Combine(copyTo, Path.GetFileName(copyFrom));
File.Copy(copyFrom, destinationPath);
```

That is the code I am currently using.

**EDIT 2**

My computer and Server are on different domains.

Comment: u mean Server path is readonly. If yes how can u think of using File.Copy, or Directory.Move. U have to have make the folder writable

Comment: No the folder I want to move/copy is readonly. Otherwise, `File.Copy` would work

Comment: why don't use just [XCOPY](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) ?

Comment: robocopy works excellent with network issues

Answer (score 1):

As @Tigran suggested, you can use cmd with xcopy (or robocopy if you prefer).

Try using this:

```
ProcessStartInfo Info = new ProcessStartInfo(); 
Info.Arguments = "/C xcopy C:\A \\server\A /I /E /Y"; 
Info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; 
Info.CreateNoWindow = true; 
Info.FileName = "cmd.exe"; 
Process.Start(Info);
```

Comment: Anychance you have an easy way to log onto the server??

Comment: @ELSheepO I don't know what you mean?

Comment: `Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.` I get this exception when I run the code.

Comment: Sorry, I meant running the `xcopy` command from cmd, it might give you a better idea where it's going wrong. VS error will be different from what cmd will be reporting.

Comment: Its giving me a `invalid drive specification` when i use the ip of the server and the server name `\\server\c:\folder_test`

Comment: That is an invalid drive path, try using the share - `\\server\c$\folder_test`

Comment: `xcopy folder* \\servername\c$\folder_test` and replacing with the ip don't work. I changed the directory to where the folder is to see if that was the problem, but that didn't work either