# Move-Item cmdlet to move a folder using C#

Tags: c#, powershell, console-application, xcopy, file-copying

I want to move a folder containing 50GB of files to a Shared folder using C#.
Iterating through directories and copying each files using FileInfo CopyTo method doesn't seems to be best option for me. I tried XCOPY Windows Command to copy. But I personally don't like the idea to call an external application which Microsoft may withdraw any time in future.
My third option is to use Windows PowerShell cmdlet Move-Item.

```
Move-Item -Path D:\Files\Server-01 -Destination \\NAS-Storage-01\Backups\Server-01\ServerFiles
```

Can anybody tell me the pros and cons using this method using C# ?

Comment: If you want to move the file, why not FileInfo.MoveTo

Comment: @SirRufo It's showing File Exists Exception for large files (40Gb). It copied a 0Kb version of the file, and throwing exception.

Answer (score 4):

`xcopy.exe` is a long-standing Windows console application that is not going anywhere.

These are a few options we have:

- `Directory.MoveTo`: This does not work across different network paths.
- Recursively move each files and subdirectories: This can take a long time if there are several files and subdirectories.
- Use console application `xcopy.exe`; as the name suggests, however, only *copying* rather than moving is performed, so you'll need an additional step after successful copying that removes the source directory.

Here is sample code that invokes `xcopy` from C#, using `Process.Start`:

```
ProcessStartInfo Info = new ProcessStartInfo(); 
Info.Arguments = "/C xcopy D:\Files\Server-01 \\NAS-Storage-01\Backups\Server-01\ServerFiles"; 
Info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; 
Info.CreateNoWindow = true; 
Info.FileName = "cmd.exe"; 
Process.Start(Info);
```

Refer below links for more details on using `xcopy` in C#-

- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/jawedmd/xcopy-using-C-Sharp-to-copy-filesfolders/
- https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true
- [Copy file(s) from one project to another using post build event...VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001822/copy-files-from-one-project-to-another-using-post-build-event-vs2010)
- [Move a directory across a network using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117700/move-a-directory-across-a-network-using-c-sharp)